# Is there any second-hand, open-source literature on Georges Bataille's essay “The Psychological Structure of Fascism”?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, continental-philosophy

A while ago, I read Bataille's [essay](https://www.jstor.org/stable/487877?seq=1) “The Psychological Structure of Fascism”, translated into English by Carl Lovitt. As I haven't followed any philosophy courses at a university (I'm mostly a self-taught "hobby" philosopher), I found the essay hard to understand.

In order to gain a better understanding, I would like to read open-source essays or articles that explain this particular Bataille piece. Could you please indicate whether relevant literary sources exist, and if so, what they are and where I can read them? I am also interested in how these sources compare to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denis Hollier and Rosalind Krauss, 'On Equivocation (Between Literature and Politics)', October , Winter, 1990, Vol. 55 (Winter, 1990), pp. 3-22, contains an extensive discussion of Bataille which includes 'The Psychological Structure of Fascism'. This is accessible through JSTOR if your library has that facility.

You will probably need JSTOR for a background article, John Brenkman, 'Introduction to Bataille',  New German Critique, No. 16 (Winter, 1979), pp. 59-63.

An online text on Bataille, with much on fascism, is available at:

https://monoskop.org/images/a/ac/Noys_Benjamin_Georges_Bataille_A_Critical_Introduction_2000.pdf

But you may have come across this already.

Comment: Thank you! [filler text]